# Kivy: Selectable Recycleview inside screen manager

Tags: python, kivy

I am new to Kivy and I am trying to to put a selectable recycleview inside a screenmanager, but I can't figure it out.
Also I can't find an example about it.

Can anyone give me an example how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be more simple to help you if you share you code.
But this is a basic example build from kivy's builtin examples.

I hope it will be helpful.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.behaviors import FocusBehavior
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.recycleboxlayout import RecycleBoxLayout
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.recycleview.layout import LayoutSelectionBehavior
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

Builder.load_string('''
#:import random random.random

<CustomScreen>:
    hue: random()
    canvas:
        Color:
            hsv: self.hue, .5, .3
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size

    Label:
        font_size: 42
        text: root.name

    Button:
        text: 'Next screen'
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'right': 1}
        size: 150, 50
        on_release: root.manager.current = root.manager.next()

<SelectableLabel>:
    # Draw a background to indicate selection
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (.0, 0.9, .1, .3) if self.selected else (0, 0, 0, 1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
<RV>:
    viewclass: 'SelectableLabel'
    SelectableRecycleBoxLayout:
        default_size: None, dp(56)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'
        multiselect: True
        touch_multiselect: True

<RVScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        RV:
        Button:
            text: 'Previous screen'
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 150, 50
            on_release: root.manager.current = root.manager.previous()

''')


class CustomScreen(Screen):
    hue = NumericProperty(0)


class SelectableRecycleBoxLayout(FocusBehavior, LayoutSelectionBehavior,
                                 RecycleBoxLayout):
    ''' Adds selection and focus behaviour to the view. '''


class SelectableLabel(RecycleDataViewBehavior, Label):
    ''' Add selection support to the Label '''
    index = None
    selected = BooleanProperty(False)
    selectable = BooleanProperty(True)

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        ''' Catch and handle the view changes '''
        self.index = index
        return super(SelectableLabel, self).refresh_view_attrs(
            rv, index, data)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        ''' Add selection on touch down '''
        if super(SelectableLabel, self).on_touch_down(touch):
            return True
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and self.selectable:
            return self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index, touch)

    def apply_selection(self, rv, index, is_selected):
        ''' Respond to the selection of items in the view. '''
        self.selected = is_selected
        if is_selected:
            print("selection changed to {0}".format(rv.data[index]))
        else:
            print("selection removed for {0}".format(rv.data[index]))


class RV(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.data = [{'text': str(x)} for x in range(10)]


class RVScreen(Screen):
    pass


class ScreenManagerApp(App):

    def build(self):
        root = ScreenManager()
        root.add_widget(CustomScreen(name='CustomScreen'))
        root.add_widget(RVScreen(name='RVScreen'))
        return root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ScreenManagerApp().run()
```

Comment: That was really helpfull , my friend. Thanks a lot

Comment: Can I put the `self.data = [{'text': str(x)} for x in range(10)]` part of the code in a function to call it ouside the recycle definition ?

Comment: Yes you can create an instance of RV widget in your python code and add it to the RVScreen in init. So you will have access to the data attribut of the objet and modify it.

Comment: Or add an id to the RV widget in the kv definition of RVScreen and access the objet through his id in your python code.